# In Krita, How to Create Graphite/Pencil Smudge Effect

Tags: brush, krita, pencil, brush-dynamics

I'm trying to emulate the following in Krita:

I take a graphite stick and rub it on a piece of paper. I then rub off the loose pieces of graphite onto a cloth. I then rub this cloth onto a piece of paper, varying the pressure to create various tonal values. I then take a circular eraser and lightly fade out certain areas to create 'cloud like' effects.

In Krita I have tried using various brushes and erasers to replicate this, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: I guess your work movements are decisive for the result. Computer simulations are much more limited, one set of settings can produce a limited part of what's possible with real materials under skilled hands. A high quality photo (not a muddy unsharp noisy mess by smartphone in poor light) of your manually achieved result increase your possibilies to get something usable. include different phases.

Comment: If you are willing to use another application, MyPaint (also free) has really good pencil smudging brushes. [See example](https://imgur.com/a/nP7RRIh). I've found it to be somewhat unique for simulating traditional media compared to other paint programs.